# Exception java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, exception

This my method and every time I run it always say "could not read column value from result set: cColor; String index out of range: 0" and throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0. Any Idea ? Can anybody tell me where's the error ?

```
    --OpenSession here--
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM db.tblUnits "
            + "WHERE csTat = :paramStation AND cbrach = :paramLocId" 
            + "AND (cType = 'repo units' OR cType = 'svc units')")
            .setParameter("paramLocId", locId)
            .setParameter("paramStation", station);

    List<Object[]> oAvailableUnits = (List<Object[]>) query.list();

    --CloseSession here--
```

Comment: why multithreading tag?

Comment: Your stack trace contains line numbers and file names that tell you where the error is. It's no good asking us here - especially if you don't share the stack trace.  In any case, it's almost certainly not in the code that you've actually shown us here.

Comment: Typo. You are missing a white space between ":paramLocId" and "AND" on the continuing `String` concatenation on the next line.

Comment: @Johny sorry, it's a mistake.

Comment: I've got it, I just changed the cColor datatype char into varchar in the database then it works. But still, I don't why java cannot read the length of the datatype char. Anyway, thanks for your responds.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that the cColor column is empty and its datatype is char, so I just changed the datatype into varchar because java cannot read the char datatype.